# Remove all content not related to index.html from the web and google

Tags: htaccess, 301-redirect

I have seen many suggestions on various redirects, but none were simple and many had no accepted answer.

I have a site I wish to completely remove from google and have only my homepage available

In that homepage I have image css and js files so they of course should not be redirected

My plan was to redirect all .html and all .php that are not the /index.html in root to the /index.html in root

Of course / should also be allowed.

So /js, /css, /img and /images should be left alone

Any other php or html page I thought I wanted to have 301 to /index.html

This worked but as pointed out in a comment, does not tell Google that the content that it indexed is no longer supposed to be there

[Stackoverflow: how-to-redirect-all-pages-only-to-index-html-using-htaccess-file-and-not-redirect](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709500/how-to-redirect-all-pages-only-to-index-html-using-htaccess-file-and-not-redirec)

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/index.html$
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* /index.html [L,R=301]
```

So my amended question is

How to tell google my content is gone and redirect all requests for content (bookmarked pages for example or external links) made to my site to /index.html

**Update**

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-docs/error410.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error-docs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* - [G]
```

almost works

But I want to return 410 on all files in 4 subfolders and whatever is under them

I have

```
/index.html
/images/
/js/
/css/
/unwantedfolder/with/stuff/imagesandhtml
/anotherunwantedfolder/with/stuff/imagesandhtml
```

I want to give 410 for now on all request to anywhere in the unwanted folders

If I add

```
RewriteRule ^unwantedfolder - [G]
```

like this

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-docs/error410.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error-docs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule .* - [G]

RewriteRule ^unwantedfolder - [G]
```

nothing happens to

```
http://www.myserver.com/unwantedfolder/bla/images/someimage.png
```

It shows without any redirection, likely due to the `!\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$` earlier
whereas

```
http://www.myserver.com/unwantedfolder/bla/somepage.html
```

does get a error410 page

Comment: Do these other pages still exist?

Comment: Yes they all exist

Comment: You seem to be focused on redirection, however, if you want to "completely remove from Google" (quickly) then you probably want to return a 410 (Gone), instead of redirecting.

Comment: @W3d That is a good idea. See my updated question. I wonder if I should then simply add .htaccess files in my 4 sub dirs that are to be "gone" and have them return 410 for all content from there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Following on from comments... since you are wanting to completely remove these pages from Google's index then simply redirecting (301) them (as requested in your original question) is not necessarily the correct thing to do. Redirection is saying that the page has *moved*. Yes, Google is likely to drop the original page from the index... eventually, but that could take some time. Trying to preserve PR by redirecting all pages to the homepage is unlikely to provide the SEO benefit you might hope for, and this is generally confusing for users.

I would suggest serving a custom 410 (Gone) for these pages, with a prominent link to the homepage (if you wish) and not actually send the user to the homepage directly - unless your homepage is your 410!?

Modifying your current .htaccess rules:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-docs/e410.html

RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error-docs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule . - [G]
```

The single hyphen (`-`) in the `RewriteRule` substitution passes the URL through unchanged. The `G` (GONE) flag returns a 410 status code and results in your custom 410 being served. An exception for the `/error-docs/` folder is also required.

**CHANGE:** Note, I've changed the `RewriteRule` pattern from `.*` (meaning "anything") to simply `.` (single period) (meaning "something"). This is an alternative to specifying an additional `RewriteCond` directive for the root URL. So, the following is unnecessary:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/
```

This should ensure that Google will remove these pages as-soon-as. You should also be able to see confirmation of this in terms of a crawl error report in GWT (yes, it is a crawl error, but it is intentional). This also provides a meaningful message to users and should encourage them to update/delete their bookmarks as required.

**UPDATE:** As mentioned in comments, the above rules still permit all the "gallery" images to be accessed (in a sub folder). In order to prevent the gallery images, we can add another `RewriteRule` following the directives above:

```
# (Above directives go here...)

RewriteRule ^gallery\d - [G]
```

This will block all URLs (including images) that start `/gallery1`, `/gallery2`, etc. (Note that the `/` prefix is intentionally omitted from the `RewriteRule` pattern.) However, the directives at the top will still allow all the other images, necessary to build your homepage.

Note that this second `RewriteRule` is entirely separate from the previous `RewriteRule` and `RewriteCond` directives above. `RewriteCond` directives only apply to the *single* `RewriteRule` that follows them. So, the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$` does not apply to this second `RewriteRule`.

### Summary

The following is the complete set of rules:

```
ErrorDocument 410 /error-docs/e410.html

RewriteEngine on

# Serve 410 to all files except:
# error documents, /index.html, / (root) and images
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/error-docs/
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/index.html
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$
RewriteRule . - [G]

# Serve 410 to EVERYTHING within the /unwantedfolder
# >>> including images <<<
RewriteRule ^unwantedfolder - [G]

# Serve 410 to EVERYTHING within the /anotherunwantedfolder
RewriteRule ^anotherunwantedfolder - [G]
```

Comment: Thanks, I will try that. So my 410 page could redirect with script to my homepage instead making Google see the 410, the users see the 410 too for a little while with explanation and then get directed to the homepage... I assume this might not work in IE with "friendly error messages" turned on

Comment: Yes, I think you could do a client-side (200) redirect with JavaScript or `meta` refresh after a period of time if you want to.  To avoid the "friendly error messages" in IE just ensure that your error document is above a certain size (512 bytes I think) - which you can do just by including a large HTML comment.

Comment: Ohhh, nice :).... I'll accept once I test this

Comment: Ok almost. Since the CONTENT but not the path is replaced by the 410 html, all css has to be absolute or the page will be really ugly

Comment: Ahh - I can still load any image under /xxxx/.../.../... - can I redirect anything from /xxxx and under and /yyyy and under but not /images

Comment: Yes, inside error documents, all client-side paths will probably need to be absolute, or _root-relative_ (that start with a slash eg. `/path/to/images/abc.jpg`) - relative paths can be problematic. Note sure what you mean by your last sentence, "redirect anything from /xxxx..." - you certainly don't want to externally redirect anything here. _Internally rewriting_ might be possible, but I wouldn't have thought should be necessary?!

Comment: I have successfully 410+client.replace all html and php, but actually all the galleries I have which are under /gallery1/images for example, are still visible and unless I actually delete them and make 404s out of them, the googler will see them and can load them all

Comment: If these gallery images are not indexed by Google then it's not a problem, however, I assume they are... then I think the easiest method is to add another `RewriteRule` to .htaccess - I'll update my answer.

Comment: Please see update. It did not quite do what I thought it would

Comment: Where did you add `RewriteRule ^/unwantedfolder/* - [G]`? "all files are GONE" - all files on the server?! This statement alone could not do this. In fact, this statement (as you have written it) should not do anything in .htaccess. The pattern should not start `/`, as I mentioned in my answer. And the trailing `*` should be omitted.

Comment: See update - if I do ^unwantedfolder - [G] all files returns [GONE]

Comment: Yes, you have added that line in the wrong place. This second `RewriteRule` should come after **all** the other directives, including the previous `RewriteRule`. Preferably after a line gap (for ease of reading). This is an entirely separate rule, not connected with the directives before it.

Comment: I think the  `!\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$` protects the images in the subfolder - see update - sorry for the long thread

Comment: And by the way, `http://www.myserver.com/` is also 410 now - it came back when I added `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/`

Comment: The code in your question should now be working for you. (?) It's possible that results are cached by your browser? The `!\.(gif|jpe?g|png|css|js)$` does not apply to the 2nd `RewriteRule` and therefore does not protect the images in the sub folder. You do need the `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !=/` directive in your example (however, I have avoided this in my example above by specifying `.` as the `RewriteRule` pattern, rather than `.*`). I have updated my answer and included a complete summary - which works OK on my server.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will test and get back to you :) - when you say `Serve 410 to EVERYTHING within the /unwantedfolder` you do mean "and below" right?

Comment: Yes, all URLs that start `/unwantedfolder`.

Comment: Seems to work well. Thanks! I had to allow robots.txt and some webmaster google fies too

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
RewriteRule (html|php)$ http://www.example.com [R=301,L]
```

This matches all requests which end either with html or php strings.

Comment: Creates a redirect loop. This one worked http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17709500/how-to-redirect-all-pages-only-to-index-html-using-htaccess-file-and-not-redirec

Comment: @mplungjan: if you found a solution to your question, please create an answer (to explain what you did) and accept it. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Sort of. Please see amended question